# While debugging, how can I jump to a function, execute it and return from where I left off?

Tags: objective-c, lldb

Say function A consists of 10 lines. I set a breakpoint at line 5, when I hit it, I want to Execute function B, before returning to A. On return, Id like the flow to continue at line 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lldb `expr` command evaluates a C/ObjC/C++ expression in the current program context, using user defined variables and variables currently in scope.

Examples:

```
expr -- functionB(17)
expr -- [self methodB]
```

Sometimes it is necessary to specify the return value explicitly, for example

```
expr -- (void)functionB(17)
```

If the function returns an Objective-C object then you can use `po` as an alias
for `expression -O  --`, in that case lldb prints the `description` of the return value.

You can also add the debugger command as an "Action" to the breakpoint,
to have it executed automatically when the breakpoint is hit:

[image]